# default uniform (array) values

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

Instead of explicitly setting uniform data for a GL program, I set 'defaults' in a simple test (fragment) shader with:

```
uniform vec3 face_rgb[] = vec3[]
(
    vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0), vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0),
    vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2), vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
);
```

Depending on the fragment's texture coordinates, an index value is formulated to look up an RGB value. (The actual RGB values are immaterial)

This works perfectly well with OS X (GL 3.2 core profile). In fact, *far better* than using an index with a `const` array. My question is - is this valid GLSL syntax, and not an implementation-dependent hack? (I have no 4+ access at the moment, but I assume the answer still applies). Also, any ideas as to why a uniform might outperform a constant array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, uniform arrays are allowed to have default values in GL 3.2. So your syntax is valid.

That doesn't mean it will always *work*, only that it's valid. Driver bugs can still get you.

Comment: Too true. I found a case where using a `uniform uint` rather than a `uniform int` actually *crashed* the (LLVM?) parser in `glCompileShader`.